# how to insert multiple choices accessing the same ref Id on each choice of checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I  have  tables  called user  and category  when Insert values in both tables at the same time .
But in category table I insert different categories using 6 checkboxes of  different choices  which are being accessed buy one name . but the problem is the choices I insert I wanted each to get the same referenced Id from the user’s table so that it will be easy for me to trace the choices of that user . by now when I insert it gives each choice a different reference id and it only use the original id on the first choice Please help me with this problem . 
below is the code but I deleted some of so that we focus on the question only.

```
  <?php



?>

<div class="form">

    <h1>Client informatinon <?php  echo $_SESSION['username']."   ";?></h1>
    <form action ="form.php" method = "post" id="postform">
<table><tr><td>

<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" name="category_name[]" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="Architecture"> Architecture
</td></td><td>
<input type="checkbox" name="category_name[]" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="townplanning">Town Planning 
</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" name="category_name[]" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="civilengineering">Civil Engineering 
                                </td><td>
<input type="checkbox" name="category_name[]" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="buildingandrenovation"> Building & Renovation
                                 </td></tr><tr><td>
                                 <input type="checkbox" name="category_name []" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="other"> Other 
        </td><td>                   
<input type="checkbox" name="category_name[]" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="interiorgaphicdesign"> Interior graphic design 

                                </td></tr>



    </form>
    </table>
</div>

<?php


if(isset($_POST['category_name'])){
foreach($_POST['category_name'] as  $value){

?>
<?php
try{
$query="INSERT INTO tish_user(username,Password,Previllage,date_created)
VALUES(:username,:Password,:Previllage,:date_created)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':username'=>$username,
':Password'=>(md5($Password)),
':Previllage'=>$Previllage,
':date_created'=>$date_created));
#end of first table
################################################
#You select the first Id and put it in a variable then 
$id_last = ("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$result =$con->prepare($id_last);
$result->execute();
$last_id = $result->fetchColumn();
############################## Last Id query Ends here
#insert into  clientinfo table 
$clientinfor="INSERT INTO tish_clientinfo
(title, firstname, lastname, nickname, idnumber, client_code, 
 company, country, city, province, address, cell, 
tel, webaddress, satifiedstatus, email, job_approval, cash_with_vat, 
cash_paid, date_registered,user_id)
VALUES(:title,:firstname,:lastname,:nickname,:idnumber,:client_code,
:company,:country,:city,:province,:address,
:cell,:tel,:webaddress,:satifiedstatus, :email, :job_approval,
:cash_with_vat,:cash_paid, :date_registered,$last_id)";
$clientinfor_insert = $con->prepare($clientinfor);
$clientinfor_insert->execute(array(
':title'=>$title,
':firstname'=>$firstname,
':lastname'=>$lastname,
':nickname'=>$nickname,
':idnumber'=>$idnumber,
':client_code'=>$client_code,
':company'=>$company,
':country'=>$country,
':city'=>$city,
':province'=>$province,
':address'=>$address,
':cell'=>$cell,
':tel'=>$tel,
':webaddress'=>$webaddress,
':satifiedstatus'=>$satifiedstatus,
':email'=>$email,
':job_approval'=>$job_approval,
':cash_with_vat'=>$cash_with_vat,
':cash_paid'=>$cash_paid,
':date_registered'=>$date_registered
));
#end of clien infor 
################################################
$security="INSERT INTO tish_security(ip_address,user_id)
VALUES(:ip_address,$last_id)";
$security_insert = $con->prepare($security);
$security_insert->execute(array(
':ip_address'=>$ip_address));
##########################end of security 
############ images 
$images ="INSERT INTO tish_images(user_id,image_name,date_registered)
VALUES($last_id,:image_name,:date_registered)";
$images_insert = $con->prepare($images);
$images_insert->execute(array(
':image_name'=>$rename,
':date_registered'=>$date_created));
##############################category 
$catigory="INSERT INTO tish_catigory(user_id,category_name)
VALUES($last_id,:category_name)";
$catigory_insert = $con->prepare($catigory);
$catigory_insert->execute(array(
':category_name'=>$value));
############# property table##########################################################
/*$property ="INSERT INTO tish_propertyinfo(user_id,date_registered)
VALUES($last_id,:date_registered)";
$property_insert = $con->prepare($images);
$property_insert->execute(array(':date_registered'=>$date_created));
*/}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
#3 fo the 
}
}
var_dump($value);



?>


</body>
```

Comment: Some example code would be useful

Comment: Could be more clear pls?

Comment: @qeremy and Andy Gee I have posted the code

Comment: So you need to gather all posted cats and insert them, right?

Comment: @qeremy I can insert em but I want each cat to have the same id since they are from I user that Id is the user_id from the user table

Comment: @Andy Gee u have put the codes

Comment: Have you considered using a hidden field for the user or a $_SESSION['user_id'] variable?

Comment: no I wanted to use that ref Id cose sometimes the admmin will be adding choices to the client table

Comment: so just set the id (if is not primary , auto increment etc). In code you set only user)id and category_name. Query should be: INSERT INTO tish_catigory(RefId, user_id,category_name) VALUES($last_id,:category_name). Not sure is this what you are looking for.

Comment: you need a way to hold checkbox per user so you should have a table for all categories - cate_id (unique, auto inc etc), categ_name; then for association user_categ - table with used_id, categ_id and refid (i would not use refid); now each time you add will have 1 entry for each categ_id and same user_id; when you edit - will just get all the categ_id for specific user, delete them and insert new checks.

Comment: @AndaIancu Great work 
All I need Is that if  I open a new accound I should select more than 2 categories and categories have category_table has cat_id  cate name and user_id as a foreign key . Is it possible to make each user_d the same as in user table for each cate ?

Comment: not sure i got your question. You want to use user_id in "link" / association table? sure you can - i.e. the table purpose is just to hold "links" user_id, categ_id and any other info you need, but i would keep only ids, all cols not null, name and other info-just get by id. 1 user_id can have multiple categ_ids: user_id =1, categ_id =1 will be (1,1), (1,2), (1,15) etc; when you get the acct categs - just query by user_id (acct)

Comment: @AndaIancu Yes  look below at qeremy's answer he explained exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the challenge is here, right? Cos, it's available to insert just one cat?

```
$catigory="INSERT INTO tish_catigory(user_id,category_name)
    VALUES($last_id,:category_name)";
```

Well, maybe this is not a real answer but assuming that you are trying to insert multiple cats but with same last_id;

```
$cats = $vals = array();
foreach ((array) $_POST['category_name'] as $cat) {
    if ('' !== ($cat = trim($cat))) {
        $cats[] = $cat;
        $vals[] = "({$last_id}, ?)";
    }
}

if (!empty($cats)) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tish_catigory (user_id, category_name) VALUES'. join(',', $vals);
    print($sql); // INSERT INTO tish_catigory (user_id, category_name) VALUES(111, ?),(111, ?)

    $sth = $con->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($cats as $i => $cat) {
        $sth->bindValue($i+1, $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $sth->execute();
    ...
}
```

See more detail here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: u are about to give me an answer Yes man I truly understand that you understood me 100% that is what am looking for you code made the databse look exactly what I want because the user_id as a ref never changed yes good but how can I convert the values to be real values cause I see (146, ?) in my db

Comment: @humphrey; Actually I suspected that I missed something and opened my pc back. So see the the answer again, maybe revision. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: thanks it works 100%  please invite me on gtalk kingmusa5 at gmail.com